# How to learn about functionalty of any java annotation within ide

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Somewhat of a generic or subjective question - but:
How to learn more about any specific annotation i.e. spring or javax annotations within my ide?

I know that basicly java annotations are just markers that can be processed via java reflection api.
Also know how to write and process my own.

What im looking for would be a way to find the said processor code or whatever to understand the annotations functionality a little more since there are often no documentations.
Any tool that could be recommended?

Comment: go to the source code documentation, they must be in javadoc

Comment: Best approach would always be the Documentation per specific api version.